# Removing a .docx file starting with ~$ via the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, ms-word

After playing around in the terminal I found that my desktop directory had a file named "~$Löp.docx" that wasn't visible outside the terminal. The file seems to be some kind of crash log for a (now deleted) word file called "Löp". I would like to remove the file and have thus far failed to enter a *rm* command that works.

When trying to echo the filename as

```
    echo "~$Löp.docx"
```

I get the output

```
    ~?p.docx
```

How can I retain the correct name for a *rm* statement?

Comment: have you tried with single quotes - echo '~$Löp.docx'

Comment: have you tried doing it with Finder?  Drag to Trash if you can get the file to show up in Finder using Show All Files...

Comment: Ye, single quotes solve it, thanks! Not really sure why it works though :I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Quote it, here's an example:

```
rm '~$some file name.docx'
```